# how to avoid overlapping views inside relativelayout in android

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

I am facing the problem while generating views dynamically in android.
I am having relative layout,inside that i am generating dynamic views.But that is overlapping only first and second view.I searched and tried more.Can any one help me to solve this.Thanks.Here is the code what i tried.
Dynamicdataadapter.java
    package com.Nithya.dynamiclist;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Dynamicdataadapter extends BaseAdapter {


    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> data; 
    int layoutid;   
    RelativeLayout itemlayout;
    ArrayList<Integer> textviewsize = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> buttonsize = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    public Dynamicdataadapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> datas, int childlayout) {

        this.context = context;     
        this.data = datas;      
        this.layoutid = childlayout;        
        textviewsize.add(2);
        textviewsize.add(5);
        textviewsize.add(3);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView ;

        Object[] textObjects = textviewsize.toArray();  

        if(row == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            row = inflater.inflate(layoutid, parent, false);

            itemlayout = (RelativeLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.itemlayout); 


            for(int room = 0 ; room < data.size() ; room++) {       

                if(position == room) {

                TextView[] textview = new TextView[(Integer)textObjects[room]]; 

                int previousid = 0;

                int currentid = 0;

                RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(context);

                rl.setId(123456);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

                rl.setLayoutParams(lp);

                for(int i =0 ; i < textview.length;i++) {

                    currentid = previousid + 1;

                    textview[i] = new TextView(context);

                    textview[i].setId(i);

                    textview[i].setText("text"+i);  

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp_btn1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);                     

                    lp_btn1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,(textview[i].getId()-1));

                    /*if(i > 0) {
                    lp_btn1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,previousid);    
                    }*/

                    textview[i].setLayoutParams(lp_btn1);
                    //textview[i].setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0);
                    rl.addView(textview[i]);

                    previousid = currentid;
                }

                 itemlayout.addView(rl);             


            }

    }
}       
return row;
}

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.Nithya.dynamiclist;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView dynamiclistview;
    ArrayList<String> datas;
    ArrayList<String> datalist;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dynamiclistview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.dynamiclistview);

        datas = new ArrayList<String>();

        datalist = new ArrayList<String>();

        datas.add("abc");
        datas.add("efg");
        datas.add("hij");




        Dynamicdataadapter dynamicadapter = new Dynamicdataadapter(this,datas,R.layout.childlayout);

        dynamiclistview.setAdapter(dynamicadapter);

        readdatafromassests();

    }


    public void readdatafromassests() {

        AssetManager assetmanager = getAssets();

        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(

                    new InputStreamReader(assetmanager.open("datasheet")));

            String readline ;

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            while((readline = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {

                Log.d("datas", ""+readline);


                if(readline.contains("Textview")) {

                    Log.d("datasheet datas", ""+readline);
                }
                builder.append(readline);
            }

            String datasheet = builder.toString();




        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LinerLayout instead of RelaytiveLayout

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView ;

        Object[] textObjects = textviewsize.toArray();  

        if(row == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            row = inflater.inflate(layoutid, parent, false);

            itemlayout = (LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.itemlayout); 


            for(int room = 0 ; room < data.size() ; room++) {       

                if(position == room) {

                    TextView[] textview = new TextView[(Integer)textObjects[room]]; 

                    int previousid = 0;

                    int currentid = 0;

                    LinearLayout rl = new LinearLayout(context);

                    rl.setId(123456);

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    lp.setLayoutDirection(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                    rl.setLayoutParams(lp);

                    for(int i =0 ; i < textview.length;i++) {

                        currentid = previousid + 1;

                        textview[i] = new TextView(context);

                        textview[i].setId(i);

                        textview[i].setText("text"+i);  

                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_btn1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);                     
                        lp_btn1.setLayoutDirection(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                        //lp_btn1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,(textview[i].getId()-1));

                        /*if(i > 0) {
                    lp_btn1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,previousid);    
                    }*/

                        textview[i].setLayoutParams(lp_btn1);
                        //textview[i].setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0);
                        rl.addView(textview[i]);

                        previousid = currentid;
                    }

                    itemlayout.addView(rl);             


                }

            }
        }       
        return row;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the problem but you are using a negative id here:

```
// first iteration i == 0

// setId(0)
textview[i].setId(i);

// RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, -1
lp_btn1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,(textview[i].getId()-1));
```

TextView with id -1 doesn't exist.